# Trigger Click on Dynamic Buttons - JS

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am creating several buttons once I read some data from a JSON file. The buttons are being create this way:

```
element.after('<button class="button ' + subcategoriesData.tag + '" category="' + category.tag + '" subcategory="' + subcategoriesData.tag + '">' + subcategoriesData.title + '</button>');
```

I want to create a click as soon as the page loads so one of these buttons is automatically selected.

I have tried to select one of the elements and trigger a `.click()` but still, this didn't work. I have also tried to find the element from its parent element and trigger a `.click()` but still, it didn't work.

Do you have any ideas what else I can try?

Comment: Instead of `click()`, you should use `on('click', function() { ... })`

Comment: @MilanChheda - Agreed, I am using that on other functions. But I want to trigger the click automatically as soon as the page loads.

Comment: then you should use `trigger('click')`

Comment: @MilanChheda - I did, but for some reason, this still doesnt work. No click is trigger once the page is laoded. I also tried to find the elements and console.log them but no elements are found. Elements are present on the page, but they are dynamically injected once I read of the JSON file

Comment: Well, then you need to create a snippet and share the code so that we understand why its not working or what is not working.

Comment: post you complete code, if your button is not in the DOM, you won#t be able to trigger a click event. another question. why you want to trigger a click event to select the button?

Comment: How are you adding the click handlers to the appended elements?

Comment: Hope you have considered the space between button and subcategoriesData.tag in your selector!!

Comment: @dag - Can I send you the code privately as its quite confidential - Will then post an update to the question with the solution

Comment: `$(element).find("button:eq(0)").click();`

Comment: @KarolaCassola just put a basic version of it in the question. The important part is are you using `click(function()...)` or `on('click', '.selector', function...)`

Comment: @PrashantShirke - Yes ofcourse, I want that space since they are seperate classes

Comment: if you send him the code, how it then confidential?

Comment: @AlivetoDie - What I mean is I just don't want to post the whole code hear. I jsut want to post a solution to my problem

Comment: @KarolaCassola you must post it here, you can obfuscate variable names or other stuff you don't want to share with others. if you want us to help, you must write a bit more what is you problem, why and how you are trying to solve. For example, why do you want do trigger a click event to select a button? this makes no sense to me, but then try to explain this in your post.

Comment: `I jsut want to post a solution to my problem`=>what that mean? do you have solution? Or after getting solution you want to post that yourself?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using jquery, you may want to consider using jQuery to create the element this way (then you don't have to worry about managing the syntax:

```
$("<button/>").attr({
   class: "button",
   category: category.tag,
   subcategory: subcategoriesData.tag
}).appendTo("#elementID");
```

The [appendTo](http://api.jquery.com/appendto/) method will append using any selector.  You can also attach to the click event using `.on("click", function(e) { })` within this statement as well.

Whatever solution you use to create the button, `$(".button:first").trigger("click")` will trigger the click event; if it's not firing, run your selector with a `.length` property check and see if it's returning 0; if it is, the selector isn't finding the button.